# realm ビュー、ストアドプロシージャを作成することは可能でしょうか

Tags: realm

SQL ServerなどのRDBで使われているような、ビュー(View)や、ストアドプロシージャの作成は、Realmでは可能なのでしょうか？
もし、RDBのビューや、ストアドプロシージャに近い機能や、やり方があれば、ご教授お願い致します。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

Realmにはいわゆるビューはありません。

ストアドプロシージャもありません。Realm Sync https://www.mongodb.com/realm/mobile/sync を利用すれば変更に対するトリガーのようなFunctionという仕組みを利用することができます。しいていえばそれが近いでしょうか。

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。いつも、早々にご回答いただき誠にありがとうございます。「Realm Sync」を調べ使ってみようと思います。